# Alternative to Selecting Block of Text (alt to select tag)

Tags: javascript, html, function, select

I am currently doing a project on creating an "exam" from a professors point of view and allowing a student to take said exams.

That being said, I have all the functionality working properly but I don't like how one thing is being handled.

Simply put, I am selecting LONG questions from a select tag. And then using the string that was selected, and adding it over to a "test" array for displaying.

The select tag makes this rather ugly, as the entire question is not being displayed... even though it does work it isn't pretty. (i am very new to front end)

Can I just get some suggestions on different ways I can go about? Selecting Data and saving the value to be sent over or displayed. Namely, I was thinking about a way to Display a Paragraph of Text and be able to Select it. While its selected I wanted to press Add question, and itll take the value (the paragraph) and add it to a variable.

Ill provide a screenshot below if it helps understand! [image]

Comment: Why not just select a question, then check `selectElement.value` upon the pressing of a button? Sent over where? You understand AJAX?

Comment: You could do `selectElement.value = underTestInputElement.value` to select from Test. Please post code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want for only one question to be selected at any time, why not use 'radio' inputs instead?

Place them in a div which is scrollable. 
Give them the same 'name' attribute. 
Give them an 'change' eventListener, loop over them, and take the value from the one that is checked.

```
<div class="myContainer">
    <label>
        <input class="myInput" type="radio" name="selectQuestion" value="My Question here..."/>
        My Question here...
    </label>
    <label>
        <input class="myInput" type="radio" name="selectQuestion" value="My Question here..."/>
        My Question here...
    </label>
</div>

.container {
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

var targets = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('myInput'));
targets.map(function(item){
    target.addEventListener('change', function(e){ 
        if (e.target.checked) { //do stuff }
    })
})
```

---

Otherwise,if multiple question could be selected at any time, just create invididual divs with 'click' eventListeners, or 'checkbox' inputs with 'change' eventListeners.

```
<div class="myContainer">
    <label>
        <input class="myInput" type="checkbox" value="My Question here..."/>
        My Question here...
    </label>
    <label>
        <input class="myInput" type="checkbox" value="My Question here..."/>
        My Question here...
    </label>
</div>
```

Opinions on design choices are kinda hard to tackle here.